# Lanczos algorithm for finding top eigenvalues of a matrix sum

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I am trying to find the top `k` leading eigenvalues of a numpy matrix (using python dot product notation)
`L@L + a*Y@Y.T`, where L and Y are a symmetric nxn and an nxd matrix, respectively.

According to the below text from [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1411.2158) paper, I should be able to calculate these leading eigenvalues with `L@(L@v) + a*X@(X.T@v)`, where I guess `v` is an arbitrary vector. The Lanczos paper they cite is [here](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11075-006-9057-z).

I'm not quite sure where to start. I know that scipy has `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh` [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html), and from the notes it looks like it uses the Lanczos algorithm - but I am at a loss as to whether it's possible to use `sparse.linalg.eigsh` for my specific use case. I googled around and didn't find a Python implementation for this very quickly -- does anybody know if I can use `sparse.linalg.eigsh` to calculate this somehow? I definitely don't want to write this algorithm myself.

I also wasn't sure whether to post this in `math.stackexchange` or here, since it's a question about the Python implementation of a very mathy thing.

[image]

Comment: [Follow up](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

You could check [scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh.html#scipy.sparse.linalg.eigsh).

```py
import numpy as np;
from scipy.sparse.linalg import eigsh;
from numpy.linalg import eigh
a = 1.4
n = 20;
d = 7;
# random symmetric n x n matrix
L = np.random.randn(n, n)
L = L + L.T

# random n x d matrix
Y = np.random.randn(n, d)

A = L @ L.T + a * Y @ Y.T # your equation
```

A must be positive-definite to use `eigsh`, this is guaranteed to be true if `a>0`.

You could check the four eigenvalues as follows

```
eigsh(La, 4)[0]
```

For reference you can compare based on [numpy.linalg.eigh](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eigh.html) that compute all the eigenvalues. Sort them, and take the last four elements of the sorted array, the results should be close.

```
np.sort(eigh(La)[0])[-4:]
```

Comment: Right, but I don't ever want to actually instantiate Y@Y.T (or, for that matter, L@L.T), since they can get huge (think millions of rows/columns). I think `scipy.sparse.LinearOperator` was the way to go.

Comment: This was not clear, so you start from a standard implementation of the Lanczos alrogithm may be useful, you only perform the standard algorithm replacing `A @ v` with `L @ (L @ T @ v) + a * Y @ ( Y.T @ v )` then the multiplications will at most produce `n x 1` sized matrix intermediate results.